# What are the pros and cons of covering a basement ceiling with drywall vs. panel board?

Tags: basement, ceiling

I'm renovating an unheated basement into a shop in a 1900's wood frame house.  The plaster has long since come down and I'm looking to cover the joists.

The goal is to insulate a bit (the floor above is pretty cold in areas), reduce noise and dust (upwards), and make the room less dark.

Any suggestions between using basic sheetrock versus using panel board like: 
http://www.homedepot.com/p/Unbranded-Thrifty-White-32-sq-ft-Hardboard-Panel-Board-709106/202090193

The basement is a little damp, but not enough to make surface rust on iron.

thank you!
steve

Comment: The panel board will do almost nothing for sound; it's very thin. Sheet rock will have better sound quality, insulation properties (although not great), but will be harder and thus take longer especially if you plan to finish it.

Comment: If you want to insulate, use insulation. Mineral wool batts between the joists would be especially good at reducing noise.

Answer (score 1):

For insulation (either thermal or acoustic) use batt insulation between the joists (e.g. Roxull or other mineral wool type which seem better for sound insulation purposes).

For additional soundproofing and a finished ceiling, you may want to consider a resilient channel ceiling, with some kind of removeable tiles (e.g. http://www.homedepot.ca/product/resilient-channel-x-12/968159).  This could lose you less ceiling height than a drop ceiling.

One consideration for having the ceiling be removeable is that you may want to run wires/pipes for the finished area of the house in future.

Answer (score 0):

Drywall is thicker, so will act as a better sound deadener. Though in terms of shop noise, you're going to need a lot more than drywall to make the room somewhat soundproof. It's also going to be better rated for fire, if that's a concern.

It's also heavy. So that's the main con. It's a real pain to haul drywall into a basement. And then you need either a friend or a drywall lift to be able to attach it to the ceiling.

Based on your list of needs, have you considered an acoustical drop ceiling instead?

Comment: That is a good idea! My main thought was to limit cost (it's a 1,000 square foot ceiling).  Acoustic tile running around $2/sq ft. vs $.40 for the paneling.

Comment: I think paneling will get you the 'brighter' goal, but that's about it. It won't likely have much bearing on sound or heat insulation.